# Recaulking a Standard size shower stall

Tags: caulking

How many tubes of caulk is needed to recaulk a standard size shower stall?

Comment: 2, maybe 3. I don't know, just buy 5 and return the rest after you're done.

Answer (score 2):

Most tubes of caulk I've seen will tell you how many linear feet of caulk bead at a standard size (usually 1/4" or 3/8") will come out of the tube.

Add up how many feet of joints you're going to need to caulk, then divide that by the number of feet each tube says it'll cover. Now you know exactly how many tubes to buy.

Comment: …then buy one more than you think you need. You can always take it back if you don't open it. Better than having to run back for another with the existing bead drying...